# Detect seller type through Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Could someone please help me with this: is it possible to obtain buy box seller type?

I mean three possible types -- Amazon, Merchant and FBA (Fulfilled by Amazon).

It is pretty easy to do grab it from product's web-page, but this does not work for automation, so I need to use MWS.

Thank you!

Comment: If you would like to get the actual seller type and seller name you would need to use the Amazon Product Advertising API, but keep in mind that it is against their policy for you to use it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN** under Products may have what you are looking for. The response includes a few things that may be helpful. There are only 2 types available, Amazon and Merchant. If the product is sold by Amazon or just Fulfilled by Amazon the FulfillmentChannel is the same for both.

1 - Summary Info - This shows you the number of Offers by each type. In the example there are 8 offers. 6 are Fulfilled by Amazon and 2 are fulfilled by Merchant.

```
        <TotalOfferCount>8</TotalOfferCount>
        <NumberOfOffers>
            <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Amazon">6</OfferCount>
            <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">2</OfferCount>
        </NumberOfOffers>
```

Also under Summary there is the BuyBoxEligibleOffers section that includes similar info.

```
        <BuyBoxEligibleOffers>
            <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Amazon">6</OfferCount>
            <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">1</OfferCount>
        </BuyBoxEligibleOffers>
```

2 - Offer data includes the following.

IsBuyBoxWinner - Tells you if this offer is the BuyBox winner.

IsFulfilledByAmazon - Is the offer fulfilled by Amazon.

```
        <Offer>
            <SubCondition>new</SubCondition>
            <SellerFeedbackRating>
                <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>100.0</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                <FeedbackCount>29</FeedbackCount>
            </SellerFeedbackRating>
            <ShippingTime minimumHours="0" maximumHours="0" availabilityType="NOW"/>
            <ListingPrice>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                <Amount>12.98</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
                <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                <Amount>0</Amount>
            </Shipping>
            <IsFulfilledByAmazon>true</IsFulfilledByAmazon>
            <IsBuyBoxWinner>false</IsBuyBoxWinner>
            <IsFeaturedMerchant>true</IsFeaturedMerchant>
        </Offer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It works for about 75% of products I have tried. 

It seems that IsBuyBoxWinner is not available due unknown reason in many products. Another call, GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN, provides fulfillmentChannel for lowest offers (and here it is possible to obtain non-FBA seller type - Merchant or Amazon), but again it is highly unreliable.

Comment: If you have an ASIN of a Product where IsBuyBoxWinner is not available send it over and I will check it out. There a few reasons why it may not be there for all Products.

Comment: For instance B002C7481G (iPad). Thank you!